# How to emulate android phone operations into emulations in desktop

Tags: android, android-emulator, seetest

Is there a way to emulate whatever operation we perform on phone to be displayed in desktop/laptop.

When my physical device is connected to my desktop/laptop, i want an emulator like feature displayed, where whatever operations i perform on phone should be displayed in the emulator.

Can we do this?

If we have any such feature, can they both be synched? meaning if i press some operation on emulator, the operation should be performed on phone.

I heard that, these can be supported like cloud based platforms like perfecto, xamarian, seetest etcc...? How they are achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Genymotion [Link Here](https://www.genymotion.com/)It is good emulator where you can download any one model of the phone and you can do whatever you like on phonebo.
other one is [Mobogenie](http://www.mobogenie.com/product/mobogenie-pc.html),these are two sort of emulators with different operations.

Comment: These are like Android emulators. There is no sync in between the physical device you connect to this emulators, right?

Comment: Such devices are not easy to find but this answer helps you

Comment: @Uday see the other answer

Answer (score 0):

[Play store app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.onaips.vnc) is used to remotely project your android device on a bigger screen ,but main problem is that your phone must be rooted.

- If you are using lollipop see this[Here](http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/5-great-uses-for-android-lollipops-built-in-screencasti-1668178784),it has inbuilt feature